# eclIpse 3.7 disable DTD validation (validation *of DTDs*)

Tags: eclipse

I have some DTD's checked into my tree that use entities. All of them get endless red (x) marks for 'DTD problem' from Eclipse indigo. I can filter them out of the problems view, but I can't see a way to get rid of the red (x) marks from the package explorer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn off the DTD Validation from the Validation preference page (or Validation property page on the project), make sure a build is done, then remove any leftover messages from the Problems view.

Of course, you've made sure that those aren't real errors?

Comment: The DTD's in question are the official W3C XHTML DTDs.